# Proving by contrapositive/contradiction/direct etc

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $a, b$ and $c$ are integers and $x, y$ and $z$ are nonzero real numbers that satisfy the following equations:

> $(xy)/(x+y)=a$ and $(xz)/(x+z)=b$ and $(yz)/(y+z)=c$.

Is $x$ rational? If so, express it as a ratio of two integers.

Honestly, I have tried to manipulate it in many ways, but I am unable to manipulate it in such a way that it is easy to prove it using either the direct method, by contrapositive method or the contradiction method. Can someone help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Please change the title to something relevant to the question. Your question is about certain properties of real/rational numbers satisfying some equations, not about the proof techniques you mention.

Comment: Hint: $xy/(x+y)=1/(1/x+1/y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac1x + \dfrac1y= \dfrac1a$, $\dfrac1x + \dfrac1z=  \dfrac1b$, $\dfrac1y + \dfrac1z=  \dfrac1c$.

Comment: Ok. is this the correct answer?

after some manipulation,

X = (2abc)/(bc-ab+ac)

Now, 2abc and bc-ab+ac are both integers since a,b,c and 2 are integers, and the sum, product and difference between integers are integers. Moreover, bc-ab+ac is not equals to zero by zero product property. Hence, x is a ratio of 2 integers, with a nonzero denominator, and by definition of rational, x is rational.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ and $\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{z}$ and $\frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$. Seeking out to get information about $x$, it makes sense to compute $\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{c}$. What happens when you do that? What is the next step? And the conclusion is?

Comment: Ok. is this the correct answer?

after some manipulation,

X = (2abc)/(bc-ab+ac)

Now, 2abc and bc-ab+ac are both integers since a,b,c and 2 are integers, and the sum, product and difference between integers are integers. Moreover, bc-ab+ac is not equals to zero by zero product property. Hence, x is a ratio of 2 integers, with a nonzero denominator, and by definition of rational, x is rational.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. is this the correct answer?

after some manipulation,

X = (2abc)/(bc-ab+ac)

Now, 2abc and bc-ab+ac are both integers since a,b,c and 2 are integers, and the sum, product and difference between integers are integers. Moreover, bc-ab+ac is not equals to zero by zero product property. Hence, x is a ratio of 2 integers, with a nonzero denominator, and by definition of rational, x is rational.